# Why does TFS Build ignore missing, unused reference in project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

When we send builds to our build server, the TFS build seems to ignore a particular reference problem in our projects. The reference problem is:

- A dll is referenced by the project
- It is not included in the solution
- **But it is not referenced by any code**

[image: Reference cannot be found]

The project will still build fine and in principle this is not a problem. The issue comes in that TFS is not using the same configuration as our Visual Studio 2010 IDE we are using. We are therefore not getting consistent build results between dev machines and build machine.

Looking at the command line arguments TFS gives msbuild, I notice one suspect looking argument:  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true - maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: Well you point to issue yourself - the setup doesnt match the one used by devs. Ensure that the referenced items is available on buildmachine. How are you referencing it, where is located on dev machine ?  From limited description it sounds as a component is not installed on buildmachine.

Comment: It is a quite strange set of circumstances that cause the issue I'm describing. The first thing to note is that, the reference is never used in any code. It has been left there as relic of some previous time the developer has used that reference and since decided against it. On their development machine, the reference exists because it has been built in another solution for another product. This allows the build to complete successfully on their development PC. Ideally, I want the TFS build to pick-up that this reference does not exist and fail but it does not currently.

Comment: Add a call to the item or use it in referenced assembly to you code that should trigger compile error when building. Either way its not TFS responsibility, TFS build calls msbuild command to compile your project same way as localy - you should star looking for solution there. If its not used in code then reference should exist in first place, if its used dynamicly at runtime then you can bind the referenced to be loaded during runtime as well. If referenced assembly doesnt have references of its own you could copy the dll into project.